# Pass a traffic from a specific domain through OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, alias

I want to pass traffic from a specific domain through `openvpn (tun0)` and the rest through `eth0`
How can I configure openvpn to work with eth0?

the domain name is set with ddclient to update dynamic dns.
but i checked with tcpdump and requests are not captured from tun0

tcpdump -vv -i  tun0

```
tcpdump: listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
23 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

what I've tried:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 x.x.x.131 up
```

ifconfig tun0

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:x.x.x.131  P-t-P:x.x.x.131  Mask:255.255.255.128
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

openvpn conf

```
client

dev tun

proto udp

remote ukm5-ovpn.domain.net 53

persist-key

persist-tun

ca ca.crt

tls-auth Wdc.key 1

cipher AES-256-CBC

comp-lzo

verb 1

mute 20

route-noexec

route-method exe

route-delay 2
```

Comment: What about your routing ? I think you should simply route your specific domain subnet to your openvpn gateway

Comment: What are the commands? openvpn added `x.x.x.131   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 tun0
`